# join 3 table jdbc

Tags: sql, join, jdbc

I have join problems with three tables.
I have the following tables:

```
Wishlists (id, user_id, itinerary_id)
Itineraries (id, name, image_id)
Images (id, name)
```

Starting from the wishlists table, I return the image assigned to a itinerary. 
How can I proceed?

```
String sql = "SELECT w.*, it.*, img.* "
                + "FROM wishlists w "
                + "INNER JOIN itineraries it ON wishlists.itinerary_id = itineraries.itinerary_id "
                + "INNER JOIN images img ON itineraries.image_id = images.image_id"
                + "WHERE user_id = ?";
```

Comment: You are missing spaces at the end of all your SQL lines.  But what is your question?  What are the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a prepared statement here:

```
String sql = "SELECT img.name FROM wishlists w ";
sql += "INNER JOIN itineraries it ON w.itinerary_id = it.id ";
sql += "INNER JOIN images img ON it.image_id = img.id ";
sql += "WHERE w.user_id = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, 100);    // for user_id = 100, for example
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String imageName = rs.getString("name");
    System.out.println("Found an image: " + imageName);
}
```

Comment: i solved this way: String sql= "SELECT w.*, it.*, img.* "
             + "FROM (wishlists w "
             + "JOIN itineraries it ON w.itinerary_id = it.itinerary_id )"
             + "JOIN images img ON it.image_id = img.image_id "
             + "WHERE user_id = ?";

Answer (score 0):

You would appear to want a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT . . .   -- explicitly list the columns
FROM wishlists w INNER JOIN
     itineraries it
     ON w.itinerary_id = i.itinerary_id INNER JOIN
     images img
     ON it.image_id = img.image_id
WHERE <what table ???>.user_id = ?;
```

Notes:

- Once you define table aliases, *use them* for the qualified column names.
- Identify the table where `user_id` comes from.
- List all the columns you want to retrieve.  You have duplicate column names, so `*` is a particularly bad idea.
- Your version of the query also missed a space before the `where`; that might just be a typo.